# React conditional subset of state element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of results from an api, stored in the state as the array 'results'.
I want a second array, 'visible_results' in the state. This should be a subset of 'results'. I'm trying to do this like this:

```
export default class SearchScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: null,
      visible_results: null,
      low_price: null,
      high_price: null,
      min_price: null,
      max_price: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = 'foo';
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          results: response.results,
          min_price: 1,
          max_price: 100
        });
        this.setState({
          low_price: this.state.min_price,
          high_price: this.state.max_price
        });
      });
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: +value
    });
    this.setState({
      visible_results: this.state.results.reduce((items, x) => {
        if (this.state.low_price <= x.price && x.price <= this.state.high_price)
          items.push(x);
        return items;
      })
    });
  };
```

The handleChange is tied to two sliders, one setting low_price, and one setting high_price. The function *should* then generate a subset of `results`, based on the new value of low_price or high_price, and save it to the state as `visible_results`.
It doesn't work. There are no errors, but visible_results always remain 'null'. The sliders definitely work. I've tried replacing the if statement with `if (1==1)` to make sure that it wasn't just an if statement typo. It did the same thing.

Comment: You should pass an array as `reduce` second argument

Comment: FYI your `reduce` just looks to be a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): `this.state.results.filter((x) => (this.state.low_price <= x.price && x.price <= this.state.high_price))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. Setting the values to `null` makes your code more complicated, I would either add a useful default value, e.g. `min_price: 0, max_price: Infinity` or just don't initialize it.
2. `this.setState` is asynchronous! If you call `setState` twice, the first call will be deferred, so `this.state` isn't yet update in the second call, so e.g. `this.state.low_price` inside the second call in `handleChange` wasn't yet updated.
3. If you don't pass an initial value to `reduce`, it will take the arrays first element, which in your case is an object, calling `push` on this won't work. You probably want `.reduce(fn, [])`, but in your case `.filter` is actually more appropriate.
4. visible_results doesn't have to be part of the state as it is determined by other state props, so just determine it on `render`

Code:

```
export default class SearchScreen extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     results: [],
     low_price: 0,
     high_price: Infinity,  
     min_price: 0,
     max_price: Infinity
  };
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   const apiUrl = 'foo';
   fetch(apiUrl)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(response => {
       this.setState({
         results: response.results,
         min_price: 1,
         max_price: 100,
         min_price: 1,
         high_price: 100,
      });
    });
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: +value
    });
  }

  render() {
   const { results, low_price, high_price } = this.state;

   const visibleResults = results.filter(item =>
      low_price <= item.price && item.price <= high_price);

     //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `.filter` makes more sense.
So I need to combine the `.setState`s?

Comment: Won't defining the visible_results in render mean that I have to re-render the page? I'm very new to react, but I thought that by having the visible results in the state, moving a slider would cause the results to appear/disappear in real time, as the state was changed by handleChange

Comment: @alex calling `setState` will rerender the component. Just try it ... it will do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Hmm, that's fine, but in the render function's return, it claims that `this.visible_results` / `this.visibleResults` is undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181430/discussion-between-alex-and-jonas-wilms).

Comment: It works, but only if `const visibleResults = ...` is changed to `var visibleResults = ...`